# Insertar datos desde un formulario a mysql con PHP

Tags: php, php5

Estoy tratando de insertar datos desde un formulario hacia MySQL con php, no lo logro, e verificado el código al parecer esta bien, los archivos se encuentran en la misma carpeta, por otro lado, en otro archivo si lleno un combobox y funciona bien, pido me ayuden les estaré agradecido. .

```
<form class="m-5" id="formularioRegisCurso" action="registraCurso.php" method="post">
                <h2 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Registro de curso</h2>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                        <label for="nombreCurso" class="form-label text-uppercase">Nombre del curso</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombreCurso" name="nombreCurso" aria-describedby="nombreCurso">
                        <div id="nombreCursoHelp" class="form-text">Ingrese el Nombre del curso.</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                        <label for="nombreCortoCurso" class="form-label text-uppercase">Nombre Corto del curso</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombreCortoCurso" name="nombreCortoCurso" aria-describedby="nombreCortoCurso">
                        <div id="nombreCortoCursoHelp" class="form-text">Ingrese el Nombre Corto del curso.</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                    <label for="observacionesCurso" class="text-uppercase">Observaciones</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="observacionesCurso" name="observacionesCurso" rows="3" placeholder="Ingresa tús observaciones"></textarea>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mt-3">
                    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success text-uppercase btn-lg btn-block" id="errores">Guardar Curso</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="row mt-3">
                  <div class="alert alert-danger btn-block text-center font-weight-bold" role="alert" id="mostrarError">
                    
                  </div> 
                </div>
            </form>

<?php

include_once "Conexion.php";

$nombre = $_POST['nombreCurso'];
$nombreCorto = $_POST['nombreCortoCurso'];
$observaciones = $_POST['observacionesCurso'];

$insertar = "INSERT INTO curso (nombre, nombrecorto, observaciones) VALUES('$nombre', '$nombreCorto', '$observaciones')";

echo $query = mysqli_query($conexion, $insertar);

?>
```

Comment: Hay errores en el error.log de Apache?

Answer (score 0):

te faltaron agregar cosas pero aqui tengo el codigo, al aprecer habia un error en la linea 14 (en el php de insertar) haces un $conexion pero nunca declaraste la variable, te dejo el codigo arreglado , son 3 archivos, 1 de conexion, 1 del formulario y 1 del php insertar, te sugiero no uses mayusculas y minusculas, en servidores web con linux luego tienes muchos problemas, saludos

este es el archivo del "**formulario**"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
<form class="m-5" id="formularioRegisCurso" action="registraCurso.php" method="post">
                <h2 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Registro de curso</h2>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                        <label for="nombreCurso" class="form-label text-uppercase">Nombre del curso</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombreCurso" name="nombreCurso" aria-describedby="nombreCurso">
                        <div id="nombreCursoHelp" class="form-text">Ingrese el Nombre del curso.</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                        <label for="nombreCortoCurso" class="form-label text-uppercase">Nombre Corto del curso</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombreCortoCurso" name="nombreCortoCurso" aria-describedby="nombreCortoCurso">
                        <div id="nombreCortoCursoHelp" class="form-text">Ingrese el Nombre Corto del curso.</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                    <label for="observacionesCurso" class="text-uppercase">Observaciones</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="observacionesCurso" name="observacionesCurso" rows="3" placeholder="Ingresa tús observaciones"></textarea>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mt-3">
                    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success text-uppercase btn-lg btn-block" id="errores">Guardar Curso</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="row mt-3">
                  <div class="alert alert-danger btn-block text-center font-weight-bold" role="alert" id="mostrarError">
                    
                  </div> 
                </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

este es el archivo "**registraCurso.php**"

```
<?php

include("conexion.php");
$con=conectar();

$nombre = $_POST['nombreCurso'];
$nombreCorto = $_POST['nombreCortoCurso'];
$observaciones = $_POST['observacionesCurso'];

$insertar = "INSERT INTO curso (nombre, nombrecorto, observaciones) VALUES(
    '$nombre', 
    '$nombreCorto', 
    '$observaciones')";

$query = mysqli_query($con, $insertar);


if ($query) {
    header('location: prueba01.php'); 
    exit();
    


    }
    else {

    }

?>
```

Este es el archivo "**conexion.php**" , lo cambie a minusculas pero ten cuidado con mayusculas y minusculas

```
<?php

function conectar(){

    $host = "localhost";
    $user ="root";
    $pass ="";
    $bd ="prueba";
    $con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass);
    mysqli_select_db($con,$bd);
    return $con;


}
?>
```

y este es el codigo de conexion de la base de datos(cree una llamada prueba)

Answer (score 0):

Si esta mismas forma es usada para guardar los datos.  Entonces te recomiendo que habilites la visualización de errores.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
```

Si usas php 7 o superior, podrás usar un bloque try catch, para ver el mensaje de error.

```
try {
       //
      } catch (\Exception $e ) {
           echo $e;
           exit;
      }
```